# How to raise a keyEvent from a test class

Tags: c#, moq, keyevent

I have created a custom text box which validates the input does some manipulation to the Text displayed if input is not valid. I have onkeypress() and ontextchanged() events to validated the input. I am trying to test this class with NUnit. My problem is how to trigger the onKeyPress event from test class.

```
public partial class InputDecimalQuantityTextBox : TextBox
{
    #region private
    //private variables
    #endregion private

    #region constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public InputDecimalQuantityTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CurrentDecimalSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        DecimalSeparatorList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                                    .Select(ci => ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .ToList();
        ignoreOnTextChanged = false;
        pasting = true;
    }

    #endregion constructor

    #region events
    /// <summary>
    /// Validate the input includes only numbers and allowed charaters(% and decimal separator)
    /// decimal separator can be a "." or "," based on region
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        pasting = false;
        e.Handled = !ValidKeyPressed(e.KeyChar);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear textbox if the text is invalid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        if (ignoreOnTextChanged)
        {
            ignoreOnTextChanged = false;
            return;
        }

        ValidateAndFormatInput();

        SelectionStart = Text.Length;
        pasting = true;
    }
    #endregion events

    private bool ValidKeyPressed(char InputCharacter)
    {
        bool isValid = true;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(InputCharacter))
        {
            isValid = false;

            if (!ValidDecimalSeparator(InputCharacter))
            {
                isValid = ValidateInput(InputCharacter);
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: What GUI are you using? winforms?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will suggest something for you, why would you unit test a form ? I think if your presentation and your business logic are separated well, you will need to only create unit tests for your business logic which will be some separate classes, when you are sure they are correct then when the form use business classes you will be sure that the presentation is working fine, so no need to go into complexities of unit testing windows forms, just create a clean and separate logic for your business so in case you shift your desktop application for example to web, then you can reuse these tested classes easily.
In case you want to make sure that the form UI is working as expected and events are attached correctly you can check automated UI testing which will test general functionality, but I think that would be efficient in complex UI applications.

Comment: Agreed - building something you can test is better than figuring out how to test what you built.

Comment: Agreed and that will be my approach going forward. Just started working and I guess you learn these things with experience. But here I want to validate the input as soon as the key is pressed and I want to test the logic that does the validation. But I guess I can create a separate class for the methods implementing the logic

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windows forms, you can set focus to the text box and send keys to the form with SendKeys.Send method:

```
textBox1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("c");
```

Comment: Thanks Eliahu, I will try this

Comment: This doesn't work, I think the key is sent to visual studio instead of textbox and it shows me a error message saying the change is not allowed when the code is running. Any other ideas on how to send the key to textbox

Comment: It works for me with a simple text box. The key is sent to the form and received by the control that has focus. From the error "change is not allowed when the code is running" it seems like you are editing the code while running.

Comment: I am not editing. I am just running the code suggested by you from within a test class.